# Android keyboard for Fancy text input

Tags: android, keyboard

I need a keyboard for Android phone which can enter fancy fonts directly. I've used apps from the play store which converts normal text to fancy looking but it's hard every time to copy from those apps and paste into desired app. This seems to fail for games like Clash of Clans.

I need a keyboard which can enter text in fancy format directly.

An example of fancy format is Fαทςγ ⓛⓞⓞⓚⓘⓝⓖ ʇxәʇ.

Comment: Fαทςγ ⓛⓞⓞⓚⓘⓝⓖ ʇxәʇ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [FancyKey Keyboard - Cool Fonts by FancyKey Keyboard Labs](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pinssible.fancykey&hl=en)

> FancyKey Keyboard is a free, customized keyboard for Android with cool fonts, 3200+ emoji, emoji arts, emoticons, personalized themes, autocorrect input and word predictions.

FancyKey offers (quoting the Play Store descripton from 2nd September 2016):

> ★Main Features★
>   ✔ 3200+ emoji & emoticons & emoji arts
>   ✔ 70+ funky fonts
>   ✔ Advanced auto-correct & auto-suggest engine
>   ✔ 50+ themes available to choose from
>   ✔ Fully customizable keyboard wallpaper and layout
>   ✔ 50+ typing sounds
>   ✔ Integrated emoji & emoticon keyboard which is compatible across all   popular apps
>   ✔ One tap to input nicely crafted emoji compositions
>   ✔ Multiple typing effects
>   ✔ SWIPE input method
>   ✔ Clipboard for multiple fast copy and paste
>   ✔ Multiple emoji styles, such as EmojiOne
>   ✔ 50+ languages

It looks like those fonts might suit your requirements:
[image: Example of the fonts]